# Let $M = \frac{1}{2}(A + {A^T})$ be real symmetric nonnegative matrix. Why does $\rho (A) \le {\lambda _{\max }}(M)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in  M_n$ be nonnegative, and consider the real symmetric nonnegative matrix
$M = \frac{1}{2}(A + {A^T})$.

Why does $\rho (A) \le {\lambda _{\max }}(M)$?

Comment: What is $\rho(A)$?

Comment: @MTurgeon  $\rho (A) = \max \{ \left| \lambda  \right|:\lambda $ is eigenvalue of $A$   $\}$)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  - What is your idea for this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $M$ is real symmetric, $\rho(M)=\max_{\|v\|_2=1}|v^TMv|$. However, when $u$ is the unit Perron vector of $A$, we have $u^TMu=\rho(A)$. Therefore $\rho(A)\le\rho(M)$. Finally, as $M$ is also nonnegative, $\rho(M)=\lambda_\max(M)$. Hence the result.

Answer (score 3):

Let $F(A)$ and $\mu(A)$ be respectively the field of values and numerical abscissa of A i.e $F(A)=${$x^* Ax;x \in C^n;\left\|x\right\|=1$} and $\mu(A)=max(z\in F(A))$. We have $\Lambda(A) \subseteq F(A)$,   $\Lambda(A)$ being the spectrum of A, so $\rho(A) \le \mu(A)$(because  $A$ is  nonnegative by definition,so $\forall \lambda>0$).It can be shown that $\mu(A)=\lambda_{max}({A+A^*\over2})$ . To see that  $\mu(A)=\lambda_{max}({A+A^*\over2})$, notice that $F(A)=F(A^*)$, so that {$x^*{(A+A^*)\over 2 }x$,$\left\|x\right\|$=1}=$F(A)$, and ${A+A^*\over2}  $being symmetric and hence normal we have $\forall z \in F(A)$ to be in the range$[\lambda_{min}({A+A^*\over2}),\lambda_{max}({A+A^*\over2})]$.